# pass array value with ngshow "ng-show="likeClicked[{{comment.id}}]" valid or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have comment widget , i am loading all comments with like and dislike button . once user like any comment i want to hide like button and show dislike  button .

```
is it valid  ??

ng-show="likeClicked[{{comment.id}}]
```

As i am trying to use like this in my code and it is not working.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="panel-body">
            Comment ::{{comment.commentline}} <br/>
            ID :: {{comment.id}}
           Likes :: {{comment.like}}  
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="incrlikes(comment)" ng-hide="likeClicked[{{comment.id}}]">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> Like
            </button>
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" ng-click="decrlikes(comment)" ng-show="likeClicked[{{comment.id}}]">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span> DisLike
            </button><br/>
```

**Script ::**

```
 $scope.incrlikes=function(a)
    {
            var selectedIndex=$scope.comments.indexOf( a );

            if(!$scope.likeClicked[$scope.comments[selectedIndex].id])
            {
            console.log('Likes increment for ::'+ $scope.comments[selectedIndex].name);
            console.log( $scope.comments[selectedIndex].id +'with index of name is '+$scope.comments[selectedIndex].name   );
           //            $scope.comments.indexOf(selectedIndex).like=$scope.comments.indexOf(selectedIndex).like+1;
            $scope.comments[selectedIndex].like=$scope.comments[selectedIndex].like+1;
            $scope.likeClicked[$scope.comments[selectedIndex].id]=true;

          }
          else
          {
            console.log('Already like' +     $scope.likeClicked[$scope.comments[selectedIndex].id]); 
          }
    };
```

For above code ng-hide,ng-show button is not working ??

Answer (score 2):

I think what you need is

```
ng-show="likeClicked[comment.id]"
```

Comment: ye u r rite :) thanks , by the way i dint downvote you i was checking ur code mean while all this happend

Comment: can you expalin why we dnt require {{}} for putting scope value ? as we need to put that everywhere in html page

Comment: The {{}} not required for the built in angular js directives like ng-show, ng-if, ng-switch, ng-bind..... Its only needed if we are referring the scope variables in the templates, not with the built in directives